# SFML 2.0 Collision class

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

I've been working on an oop version of snake use the sfml 2.0 library and I have a separate class for handling collisions. Here's the code:

## include "collision.hpp"

```
bool sfc::Sprite::collision(sfc::Sprite sprite2) {
  this->setBounds();
  sprite2.setBounds();

  if (top > sprite2.bottom ||  bottom < sprite2.top ||  left > sprite2.right ||  right < sprite2.left) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

void sfc::Sprite::colMove(sf::Vector2f &movement, sfc::Sprite sprite2) {
  if (!this->collision(sprite2)) {
    this->move(movement);
  }
}

void sfc::Sprite::colMove(float x, float y, sfc::Sprite sprite2) {
  if (!this->collision(sprite2)) {
    this->move(x, y);
  }
}

void sfc::Sprite::setBounds() {
  top = this->getPosition().y;
  bottom = this->getPosition().y + this->getTexture()->getSize().y;
  left = this->getPosition().x;
  right = this->getPosition().x + this->getTexture()->getSize().y;
}
```

The only problem is once the collision event happens, the sprite is stuck for the rest of the window life. How can I get it so that on that collision it does not stick there. Thanks! ~Michael

Edit: I understand that the sprite is not allowed to move after collision occurs but I don't know any other way of stopping the sprite from moving after the collision.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that once your sprite enters in collision with your sprite2 it can't move anymore. You could try reverting the movement to the previous x and y if you detect collision. Or check if the place you will move to is empty.

```
 bool sfc::Sprite::collision(sfc::Sprite sprite2, float x, float y) {
  this->setBounds();
  sprite2.setBounds();

  if (top > sprite2.bottom + y ||  bottom < sprite2.top - y ||  left > sprite2.right +x||  right < sprite2.left - y ) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

that is for the collision and then

```
void sfc::Sprite::colMove(float x, float y, sfc::Sprite sprite2) {
  if (!this->collision(sprite2, x, y)) {
    this->move(x, y);
  }
}
```

note: i don't remember correctly the coordinate system used by sfml so check the + and -

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I understood that my sprite was not allowed to move after the collision but the code you posted above only changes the distance between the two sprites before collision occurs.

Comment: oh i see. i don't remember much about smfl, but i hope it helped you a little anyway